# Howto hook into a running Heroku Clojure repl

Tags: deployment, heroku, clojure

Is there a way to hook into a heroku dyno's running Clojure repl? There are 2 cases where I want to see what's going on.

- i. I want to initialize my MongoLab DB. But when I get to my [heroku repl](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure#console), if I try to make a DB call, I get an error.
- ii. When running my Clojure app on Heroku, I get a NullPointerException. But the logs don't show me enough info to know where to look. So it would be nice to dig into the dyno's running repl.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

heroku's filesystem is read-only, not support MongoLab DB, source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem, heroku's clojure docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/clojure

Comment: I'll take a look at [Drawbridge](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/debugging-clojure). But MongoLab is absolutely supported ([see here](https://addons.heroku.com/mongolab)).